# What is the complexity of this code?

Tags: graphics, geometry, complexity-theory, polygon

[image]

I have a the above model represented in a Face Table List where the `F1, F2,...F_n` are the faces of the model and their face number is the index of the list array. Each list element is another array of 3 vertices. And each vertex is an array of 3 integers representing its `x,y,z` coordinates.

I want to find out all the neighbouring faces of the vertex with coordinates `(x2, y2, z2)`. I came out with this code that I believe would do the task:

```
List faceList;   //say the faceList is the table in the picture above.
int[] targetVertex = {x2, y2, z2};   //say this is the vertex I want to find with coordinates (x2, y2, z2)
List faceIndexFoundList; //This is the result, which is a list of index of the neighbouring faces of the targetVertex

for(int i=0; i<faceList.length; i++) {
   bool vertexMatched = true;
   for(int j=0; j<faceList[i].length; j++) {
      if(faceList[i][j][0] != targetVertex[0] && faceList[i][j][1] != targetVertex[1] && faceList[i][j][2] != targetVertex[2]) {
         vertexMatched = false;
         break;
      }
   }
   if(vertexMatched == true) {
      faceIndexFoundList.add(i);
   }
}
```

I was told that the complexity to do the task is O(N^2). But with the code that I have, it looks like only O(N). The length of `targetVertex` is 3 since there is only 3 vertices per polygon. So, the second inner loop is merely a constant. Then, I left only with the outer `for` loop, which is then O(N) only.

What is the complexity of the code that I have above? What could I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty obvious that in the worst case you must look at each vertex of each polygon.

This is just O(size of the table) in your post, which in turn is the sum of all row lengths or the sum of all polygon vertex counts, whichever you prefer.

If you say polygons have no more than m vertices and there are n polygons, then the algorithm is O(mn).

FWIW it's possible to get the answer with no searching at all with a more sophisticated data structure.  See for example [the winged edge data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winged_edge) and others.  In this case, you just go to the vertex you're interested in and traverse the links that connect all adjacent polygons.  Cost is constant for each polygon in the output.

These fancier data structures for polygonal meshes support lots of frequently used operations with wonderful efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

The complexity is (aproximatly) faceList.length * faceList[i].length, these are independent, but can both grow very large, and as they grow they will each approch infinity at which point (conceptually) they will converge on n, resulting in the complexity being O(n^2)

If the vertex list is explicitly limited to 3, then the complexity becomes faceList[i].length * 3, which is O(n)

Comment: Exactly.  The first loop runs faceList.Length times and the second loop according the description always contains only three vertices therefore it always runs up to 3 times.  So big O becomes `faceList.Length * 3 = N * 3 = 3N = O(N)`

Comment: Nitpick: if two distinct variables `n` and `m` "approach infinity" then this does not imply that the product is `O(n^2)` - it depends on how the two are related. For example, if `m` grows proportionately to the square of `n` then you would get `O(n^3)`

Comment: @mikera: you are right of course, my description is vastly simplifed to show why this would (lacking other data) normally be O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Use_in_computer_science):

> Big O notation is used to describe the limiting behavior of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value or infinity.

In this single case you might only be running the one `for` loop.  But what happens when the number of vertices of the polygon approaches infinity?  Do the majority of the cases cause the second `for` loop to run, or to break?  This will determine whether your function is `O(n)` or `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Thanks! For every `j` vertices polygons, there will be `j` neighbouring faces. Therefore, if there were `i`number of faces, then the second `for` loop would break for `i-j` times. So in this case, would it be `O(n)` or `O(n^2)`? Should the `n` that is approaching infinity in the big-o referring to the number of vertices (number of elements in the second loop), or the number of faces (number of elements in the first loop)?

Comment: Not quite sure, but I'm interested in the answer so I'm starting a bounty on the question.  Big O notation's interesting, but I'm shaky on the details so hopefully we get someone more knowledgable in here soon!